# What should I do to save the final image in a .png format?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image

I couldn't save my rendered image in a .png format. When I press F3 key it only increases my PC screen brightness.

Answer (score 2):

On the **Render result screen**, Please follow the menu **Image -> Save as Image**, as shown below:

[image]

Seems that you are using a laptop, you will have some combination, you may try 
function key + f3 or function key + shift + f3
If you share your laptop model number, I may pin point alternative for you!

Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer as true if it worked for you, as it will be useful for others too.

Comment: If you are going to be using blender constantly, it would be better if you can re-configure the shortcuts on the operating system to work with keys that do not conflict with blender. Usually combinations that use the windows key or the FN key on laptops should be safe, as blender uses none of those as shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Below the render view, you can click *Image* and select *Save As Image*.